# Use attributes with weird chars in Marionette / underscore template

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have a model with attributes names like `@id`, `@type`, etc.

If I try to use `<%= @id %>` in a `Marionette.ItemView` template (with Underscore) I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Using the syntax `['@id']` does not produce the expected result.

Do I have to override the `serializeData` function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore templates require JavaScript expressions inside `<%= ... %>`, the compiled template uses [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) so you can usually reference object properties as though they were variables. Your problem is that `@id` is not a valid JavaScript expression.

So yes, providing your own [`serializeData`](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-13) to remove the `@`s is probably your best bet. Another possibility would be to use the `variable` option with [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the **variable** setting. This can significantly improve the speed at which a template is able to render.
>
> ```
> _.template("Using 'with': <%= data.answer %>", {answer: 'no'}, {variable: 'data'});
> => "Using 'with': no"
> ```

Then you could use things like `<%= data['@id'] %>`; the problem is that getting this approach to work with Marionette might be more work than simply cleaning up the `@`s in a custom `serializeData` method.