# Access property with special character in underscore template?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

My model has properties with special characters (received from a web service) that I need to reference using bracket notation. Is there a way I can reference these properties when rendering my template with `this.model.toJSON()`? I currently am overriding toJSON to map them.

**Update**, another way that is probably the best/easiest yet: `$(this.el).html(this.template({ data: this.model.toJSON() }));` and referencing the property with `data['@invalid-property-#characters']`.

**Update**, example template:

```
<span><%= section_name %></span>
<span><%= @type %></span <!-- won't work -->
<span><%= data['@type'] %></span> <!-- works -->
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your asking, but you can *html escape* values in [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) using the following syntax `<%- … %>`, if you are asking how to change the syntax style then you can change that by passing in a regex to `_.templateSettings`.

Comment: I'm just talking about printing properties in my template. See my edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use attributes with weird chars in Marionette / underscore template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096106/use-attributes-with-weird-chars-in-marionette-underscore-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Override `toJSON` in the model and map the properties with special characters differently.
2. Scope the variable in order to use bracket syntax. `this.template({ scopedVariable: this.model.toJSON() })` and in the template `<%= scopedVariable['@invalid-variable-#name'] %>`

Answer (score -1):

```
@type
```

is not a valid javascript variable name so it is not going to work.

EDIT :

**there is no other solution than either changing your property name ,** or scoping your model in a variable by passing an object like you did in your question. This is no magic just javascript, if it's not going to work in javascript it's not going to work in your underscore template , **period.**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mike : It does answer the question : You cant do that is the answer. If you have an answer , why dont you write it instead of critizing mine ?

Comment: I don't have `@data` anywhere in my example. I know its an illegal character. I'm looking for a solution that might be better than the 2 I've given.

Comment: I meant @type. and there is no other solution than either changing your variable names , or scoping your model in a variable by passing an object like you did in your question. This is no magic just javascript.